Is this depth search correct (DFS) Shouldn't one act according to the LIFO principle?

Shouldn't we actually continue with C after A, thought a depth search, follows the LIFO principle, isn't C the last node added in this case and shouldn't we expand C before B?

It depends on the order of the children. It is usually the case that children in rooted trees are browsed from left to right.
Also, if the DFS is written recursively, then this is indeed the correct ordering if children are ordered from left to right, like in the algorithm:
DFS(v):
    if v has not been seen:
        for u a child of v:
            DFS(u)

Indeed, $B$ would be the first child to be seen, and so the first child to explore. There is no explicit stack here, only the recursion stack.
